# Dynamically set style attributes for an Image in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to alternate the placement of images on my application. I want every picture to have a marginLeft of 30%, then the next image to have a marginRight of 30%, and so on...To do so, I'm dynamically rendering the style props for an image based on the value of a bool I have set in my state:

```
class Experience extends Component {
    state = {
        leftSide: true,
        experience: // an Object with data here that I'm mapping to image tags
    }

    determinePosition() {
        const { leftSide } = this.state;

        if (leftSide) {
          this.setState({ leftSide: false });
          return { marginRight: "30%" };
        } 
        else {
          this.setState({ leftSide: true });
          return { marginLeft: "30%" };
        }
  }

  render() {
    {Object.keys(experience).map((key) => (
          <Container key={key} className="experience">
            <img
              src={experience[key].imageUrl}
              alt="Company logo"
              id={key}
              style={this.determinePosition()}
            />
          </Container>

    }
  }

export default Experience;
```

However, because the state is endless being changed, I'm getting the error message:
 `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: Try style={this.determinePosition} (no brackets)

Comment: Tried that, and got: Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

Comment: I see. Anyway, you got a reply, so all good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about use an unordered list `<ul>` to contain your images, then all you have to do is style the list items like so:

```css
li { margin-left: 30%;
li:nth-child(odd) { margin-right: 30%; }
```

Comment: Great idea! I used li:nth-child(odd) and li:nth-child(even), and this did the trick.